# Is it possible to render a single div element in javafx webview from url?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

is it possible to render a single div element in javafx webview from url?

I know how to open a webview and display a whole website in javafx with webview and webengine. But I could not find any way to render a single div element from the website with the related css/js.
Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Download the `html`, strip out the elements you need and rebuild it into a new `html` `String`/file and load it instead?

Comment: what about the css / js part which are needed to display that element? I think that would just break the look of the element, wouldn't it?

Comment: Create a brand new html file, including references to all the JS/CSS, but only including the element you want in the body